# REST API URL that can be used to retrieve the metadata for a resource contained in a storage bucket

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, metadata, bucket

I am new to Cloud and I've been practising it for a while. I have a use case.
I want to retrieve the metadata of images in the bucket through a suitable REST API. I searched in API explorer and found **Cloud Resource Manager API** that could help retrieve the metadata but after exploring it I couldn't figure out the link.
[API Required Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QI1Or.png)

Can someone help me to understand what to put in the parent field?

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong REST API.

The REST API endpoint is:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/BUCKET_NAME/o/OBJECT_NAME
```

To view metadata, here is an example using the REST API in curl:

```
gcloud auth application-default login

BUCKET=BUCKET_NAME
OBJECT=OBJECT_NAME
URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/$BUCKET/o/$OBJECT
TOKEN=$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)

curl -v -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" $URL
```

Comment: What if I have to test this through Cloud Shell Script? Does this same goes as script? @john-hanley

Comment: @A.Basit Yes, this will work in Cloud Shell.